# MySQL - Get previous row with a same identifier

Tags: sql, mysql, join, row, identifier

I need help in constructing an MySQL Statement where I need to find previous rows in the same table.

My data looks like this:

history_id (auto increment), object_id (exists multiple times), timestamp, ...

example:

```
1, 2593, 2018-08-07 09:37:21
2, 2593, 2018-08-07 09:52:54
3,   15, 2018-08-07 10:41:15
4, 2593, 2018-08-07 09:57:36
```

Some properties of this data:

- the higher the auto increment gets the later the timestamp is for the same object id
- it is possible that there is only one row for one object_id at all
- the combination of object_id and timestamp is always unique, no duplicates are possible

For every row I need to find the most previous row with the same object_id.

I found this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/how-do-i-get-the-current-and-next-greater-value-in-one-select and worked through the examples but I was not able to solve my problem.

I just tested around a bit and got to this point:

```
SELECT
    i1.history_id,
    i1.object_id,
    i1.timestamp AS state_time,
    i2.timestamp AS previous_time
FROM
    history AS i1
    LEFT JOIN (
        select  timestamp as timestamp,history_id as history_id,object_id as object_id
        from        history
        group by object_id
        ) AS i2 on i2.object_id = i1.object_id and i2.history_id < i1.history_id
```

Now I only need to cut of the subquery that I only get the highest value of history_id for each row but its not working when I use limit 1, because then I will get only one value at all.

Do you have any Idea on how to solve this problem? Or you may have better and more efficient techniques?

Performance is a point here because I have 3.1 million rows growing higher..

Thank you!

Comment: Definitely heading in the wrong direction! See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

The best direction is to use `window` function. Simple `lag(timestamp)` would do the job with proper order by clause. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag

But if all You need is

> to cut of the subquery that I only get the highest value of history_id for each row but its not working when I use limit 1

Then change subquery from

```
select  timestamp as timestamp,history_id as history_id,object_id as object_id
        from        history
        group by object_id
```

to

```
select  object_id as object_id, MAX(history_id) as history_id, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
        from        history
        group by object_id
```

In general You should not SELECT more columns, than You have in GROUP BY clause, unless they are enclosed with aggregate function.

Comment: I also thought about that (I'm sorry I should have mentioned that.) but then inside the subquery the highest value is higher then the one of the row that is compared from the outer query. Somehow I need to do something in the subquery like: where history_id < i1.history_id. But this results in an SQL Error?

Comment: With `lag` function there is not need for subquery. You simply should do `SELECT history_id, object_id, timestamp as state_time, lag(timestamp) as prev_timefrom history WINDOW w AS (order by object_id, timestamp);` But be carefull, when the object_id changes, You may get timestamp from previous object_id. (not sure how MySQL handles this). Then You can replace `lag(timestamp) as prev_time` with `case when lag(object_id) != object_id then NULL else lag(timestamp) end as prev_time`